# JavaScript global variable in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, global-variables

I'm making a webapp that allows people to see the location of buses on Google maps. I'm having some problems with global variables in JavaScript. window.variable doesn't work for me. Neither does defining the variable outside the all the functions works. Here is my complete client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
// is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

var old = [];

function getLocation()
{
  $.get( "http://54.86.161.214/EC_bus_app/get_location.php", function( data ) {
    old=[];
    var buses = data;
    var number_of_buses = buses.slice(0,1);
    buses = buses.slice(2);
    buses = buses.slice(0,-1);

    var bus_coordinates_and_numbers = buses.split(/[ ]+/);
    var length_of_array = bus_coordinates_and_numbers.length;

  // Turn a single dimensional array into a multi-dimensional array

    for (var index = 0; index < bus_coordinates_and_numbers.length; index+= 3)
        old.push( bus_coordinates_and_numbers.slice(index, index + 3) );
    console.log(old);
    //initialize(old);

  });
}

setInterval(getLocation, 10000);

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

var image = "icon_97.png";

  for (i=0;i<old.length; i = i + 1){
    var x = old[i][0];
    var y = old[i][1];
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
    var busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: old[i][2]
    });
  }

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Your location'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The variable in question is `old`. I can pass it to the initialize function from within the `get location` function using `initialize(old);`. However, as you can see, I'm using a timer, and `initialize(old);` causes the entire map to reload again and again, whereas I only want the location markers to load again and again.

Comment: Your problem is not with global variables.  It is with asynchronous functions.  You need to initialize the map, then request data (asynchronous request), make markers on the map, then periodically update them.

Comment: [fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/fx7jx5qn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by moving `getLocation()` inside `initialize()`. But what @geocodezip said in the comments also answers my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with global variables. It is with asynchronous functions. You need to initialize the map, then request data (asynchronous request), make markers on the map, then periodically update them.